# Is it wrong to use ffmpeg on images?

Tags: ffmpeg

For some reason, I can just do `ffmpeg -i image.webp image.png` to convert an image, even though FFmpeg is for videos. Is there anything wrong with this? Is it intended behavior?

Comment: it's documented, so, I guess it's a valid thing to do ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If it works, it works.

Comment: @vssher Please don't do that. Voting should be based on quality of the question, not on your opinion on others' opinion about it.

Comment: is there a problem with the quality of this question? sorry if it's invalid, it would be nice to understand why though

Comment: It works on images and videos, but it is more focused on videos. Image Magick is more focused on images.

Comment: @KTibow That's a question to whoever downvoted. Then haven't left an explanatory comment unfortunately.

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: The issue with this question is it's basic premise: "is it wrong to..." as others have noted, if it works it works, and also the method is documented. OP has not actually indicated anything failed, or given any other question except if it's "wrong" to use the software in a given way.

Comment: my question was whether it was intended, as i could not find any documentation that said you could do it when i was searching. anyway i have my answer now.